# Disqus: change captions after success with jQuery

Tags: jquery, disqus

Disqus automatically places defined captions upon request. For example: Add new Comment

I've tried to change its value with jquery on ready():

```
$('#dsq-new-post h3').text('Paticipa con tu cuenta favorita');
```

No success :( ... how can i know when disqus script is finished parsing the data so i can change the caption value of h3?

BTW, this is Disqus' call:

```
(function(){
var dsq = document.createElement('script');
dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = 'http://xxxxxxxx.disqus.com/embed.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

Comment: did you try .val('new text') or .html('new text or html')

Comment: Is this after an ajax request?

Comment: @London yes, the problem is that the ready() statement happens BEFORE disqus' script finishes parsing the data... i need a way to know when that happens.

@Nick Craver: no, plain JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer andufo. It works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.disqus_no_style = true;

  $.getScript('http://sitename.disqus.com/embed.js', function() {
    var loader = setInterval(function() {
      if($('#disqus_thread').html().length) {
        clearInterval(loader);
        disqusReady();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

  function disqusReady() {
    //whatever you can imagine
  }
});
```

You can comment out the $.getscript line and ending }); as well as the window.disqus_no_style = true; line.

I had a similar problem and posted this question. Mohamed attempted to answer me and his answer did not work but he'd posted a link to his code at github and I found the right answer there.

[Chrome Extension iframe dom reference disqus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398899/chrome-extension-iframe-dom-reference-disqus)

https://gist.github.com/471999

Comment: Hey Darin, mind helping me out as well? This is my issue: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/customize-disqus-wp-plugins-mark-up-with-jquery and I cannot make your code work.

Comment: I get an error page when I try to navigate to the link provided in your post on that page.  I think your problem, though, is CSS precedence. You should be able to test that pretty easily by manipulating an HTML attribute instead of a CSS attribute. Like converting all H3 to H1. If that works, and I am pretty sure it will, then the problem really is an issue with how the CSS ruleset applies conflicting instructions.

Comment: Sorry, new link is http://demo.crozer.me/era-wp/guide-of-the-week-moving-objects - I have actually tried to manipulate the HTML, like changing the .text() or .html(), or removing an object. I realized that your code works if I directly write my code after the clearInterval (i.e. not inside the disqusReady function, which is outside). Furthermore, I also realized that sometimes my changes worked, and sometimes they did not. This is really driving me insane. Is there any possibility we could have a chat and you could check the site live?

Comment: I've got to get ready for work and get out of here. Today and tomorrow I won't have a lot of time but I'll try to check in with you tomorrow night after 8pm CST.

Comment: cr0z3r I haven't forgotten you buddy. I had car trouble the last couple of days. Tonight I work late but tomorrow I get home a little earlier.

Comment: I actually managed to work it out. The only issue was that #disqus_thread always exists, so setting an Interval for it wasn't the appropriate solution; instead, checking whether #dsq_reply exists does the trick. Thank you either way!!

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution also works, although the original text appears first, then is replaced with the new text, which is less then ideal.

```
function disqus_callback() {
  $('#dsq-reply h3').text('Add Your Answer');
}
```